# Handling and calculate the formula saved in the database

Tags: c#, .net, database, linq, entity-framework

The following link descrip about Non-Relational field types in database:
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Force_Database

one of field types is the formula fields:

> Formula - A read-only field holding data generated from a formula
>   expression.

I use c# and entity framework as development tools.Business logic in this application will be changed over months.I want to let system administrators(some users) to define application 's formula and store in the database.
My Question: **How can is calculate formulas ,stored in database dynamically with c#?!**
(formula contains: static values,field names,functions,operators and ...).

What are your ideas?

- Can i convert formulas(string) to linq query and execute dynamicaly?!!
- ...!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options come to mind:

- If the operations are fairly simple you can have a look at the new [Roslyn CTP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/10/19/introducing-the-microsoft-roslyn-ctp.aspx). Roslyn is a new managed compiler for Visual Studio that you can use in your own code. It let's you easily compile snippets of code and execute them.
- Another thing you can have a look at are Expression Trees. With the [Expression Tree Serializer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/exprserialization) you can serialize an expression tree and possible save it in a database. But then you will need some kind of user interface to construct those expression trees. On the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) you can find some examples of how to construct an expression tree by hand

Comment: how can i use formula(string) in Expression Tree Serializer?!!

Comment: You have to represent your formula as an Expression Tree. That's a lot more complex then a simple 'a + b' string but it gives you the flexibility to save it to the database and compile and execute it at runtime.